# rake db:migrate depreciated...what do I do?

Tags: rake

I tried updating the gems. I discovered the problems after trying to do heroku rake db:migrate and it said:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- faker
/app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Then when I do rake db:migrate it says:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:84.
```

Not quite sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm not sure why this happened all of a sudden randomly but rolling back to an earlier version of rubygems solved the issue. Here's the code:

```
sudo gem update --system 1.6.2
```